# Obtaining Std Dev & t value in lmer() estimates

Tags: r, lme4, lmer

I'm trying to use lmer() to construct a linear mixed effects model, but the output I get simply looks like this

```
> model <- lmer(elogit_ToTarget ~ (Age..vA..months. + EVT_GSV + DDNotAgeSensitive)*(OrthTime + OrthTime2) +
+                 ( OrthTime + OrthTime2 | Subject ), data=d)
> print(model, correlation=F)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: elogit_ToTarget ~ (Age..vA..months. + EVT_GSV + DDNotAgeSensitive) *  
    (OrthTime + OrthTime2) + (OrthTime + OrthTime2 | Subject)
   Data: d
REML criterion at convergence: 373.2443
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev. Corr       
 Subject  (Intercept) 0.4440              
          OrthTime    2.7986    0.65      
          OrthTime2   1.0893   -0.12 -0.21
 Residual             0.2486              
Number of obs: 1060, groups: Subject, 30
Fixed Effects:
                (Intercept)             Age..vA..months.                      EVT_GSV            DDNotAgeSensitive  
                  -3.516428                     0.008027                     0.026585                    -0.130812  
                   OrthTime                    OrthTime2    Age..vA..months.:OrthTime   Age..vA..months.:OrthTime2  
                 -10.282966                     2.193035                     0.070552                     0.001379  
           EVT_GSV:OrthTime            EVT_GSV:OrthTime2   DDNotAgeSensitive:OrthTime  DDNotAgeSensitive:OrthTime2  
                   0.106536                    -0.037707                     1.532189                     2.627951
```

In other examples that I've seen, there are columns for Standard Error and t-value in addition to the estimates, but this doesn't appear to be an option that can be specified.  How can I get these?

Comment: Instead of `print`, try `summary`.  Or just type `model`. You can also look at the names of `lmer`

Comment: Wow, so simple.  Summary works.  I'm clearly new to this - thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If your interested in the fixed effects only, you can use `coef(summary(model))`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `summary(model)`; if you want to extract the fixed-effect coefficient table, use `coef(summary(model))`.